# Batch File Issue - Save Input To Text With Spaces

Tags: file, variables, input, batch-file, space

I'm trying to make a helpful batch file for work and for it, I'm trying to input notes/text to a .txt file via a variable. It works great with just entering text without spaces (ex: "test"), but once you type something with at least 1 space in it, the cmd closes out. (ex: "test test") I can't figure out why this is happening so I'm left with you guys here. Any/all help would be appreciated!

```
@echo off

color 9F
title Notes
CLS

del %UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt
echo Issue/Request: >> %UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt

:StartCallNotes
CLS

echo ================== Notes =================
type %UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt
echo ==========================================

set /p NotesEnter=Enter Notes: 

set NewNote="%NotesEnter%"

if %NotesEnter% == CLS goTo :CLS

echo %NotesEnter% >> "%UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt"

goTo :StartCallNotes

:CLS
del %UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt
echo Issue/Request: >> "%UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt"
goTo :StartCallNotes

exit
```

Comment: How you enter the value if it's contain spaces ? "test test" or just test test (without quotes) ?

Comment: Without the quotes. But it also closes if you enter quotes anywhere in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is when you compare the user's input with CLS.
Try to put quotes in %NotesEnter% when compare the value like this :

```
@echo off

color 9F
title Notes
CLS

del %UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt
echo Issue/Request: >> %UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt

:StartCallNotes
CLS

echo ================== Notes =================
type %UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt
echo ==========================================

set /p NotesEnter=Enter Notes: 

set NewNote="%NotesEnter%"

REM if user doesn't input the value echo a new line
if "%NotesEnter%" == "" echo. >> "%UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt"

if "%NotesEnter%" == CLS goTo :CLS

if NOT "%NotesEnter%" == "" echo %NotesEnter% >> "%UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt"

REM reset the variable value
set NotesEnter=

goTo :StartCallNotes

:CLS
del %UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt
echo Issue/Request: >> "%UserProfile%\Documents\Notes.txt"
goTo :StartCallNotes

exit
```

Comment: just tips : if you want to find the code that caused the error, just comment the @echo off line. :)

Comment: Haha thanks. Also, how would I add an empty space to a text file? Hitting enter brings up "Echo is off" and if I type test and keep hitting enter, it repeats the last message. I was assuming that maybe this will help initially before typing something out if you hit enter. It leaves an empty space followed by "Echo is off":

if not defined NotesEnter echo. >> %UserProfile%\Desktop\Notes.txt

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again! :) If I could +rep again, I would. Haha